# Has the mathematics of 4d-tetris, or any other 4-dimensional polyforms been studied?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

There are a few variations of 4d tetris games floating around the internet, but I'm more interested to know if there's been mathematical research done in the area of 4d polyforms. I assume that the 4d-tetris games out there are based off polytessaminos (i.e. multiple tesseracts adjacent to each other), but from a quick search, I couldn't find any research on them, at least not with the name "polytessamino".